# How to develop a brach when it is merged with other developing branches

Tags: git, git-merge, git-workflow

Imagine two branches: 124 (mine) and 158, both are under development.

1. I merge `commitA` of 158 into 124.
2. In 158-`commitA` files are renamed, content changed after rename, now it is 158-`commitB`.
3. 158 raised a PR, which was squash-merged to master. After that 158's remote branch was closed.
4. I wasn't aware of #2 and #3, so did not keep 124 in sync.
5. I started to open a PR for 124, and found that the files I merged from 158-`commitA` are now appearing as new files in the PR/merge of 124.
6. I checked 158's PR, found the changes, modified these on 124 too.

#6 seems like unnecessary work that git should be able to handle automatically. Is there any way I can avoid this manual work?

Comment: By following best practices for git branching as mentioned here: https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Please update your question, clarifying #1 (was it a true merge, a cherry-pick, or a rebase?) and #2 (was 158-`commitB` a history rewrite of 158-`commitA`?)

Comment: @Inigo The question already specifies that branch 158 was "squash-merged" to master, which effectively answers both of your questions: a squash is a type of history rewrite.

Comment: No, that is not clear at all, and I think you don't understand my questions. It is the job of the question asker to take the time to make the question very clear and unambiguous, and answer questions of clarification, because many SO users often use the wrong terms and people waste time answering with the wrong assumptions.  My first question wasn't about the PR, it was about *your* "merge" of `commitA` from 158. I want to make sure it was a merge, not a cherry pick. It would mean, amongst other things, that `commitA` is the first commit after the fork point of your two branches.

Comment: Likewise, my second question was NOT about the PR, but about the nature of `commitB`. Was it a commit on top of `commitA`? Or was `commitA` amended and replaced by `commitB`? This matters because they result in different commit histories, and changes the possibilities for finding a non-manual solution. Because as @IMSoP points out, rewriting history is a bad thing when multiple people are working on the same code. But depending upon how history was rewritten, there may or may not be easier ways to dig yourself out of the hole. See my comment to @IMSoP's answer.

Comment: @Inigo As soon as a squash merge has happened, the nature of commitA and commitB, and how they appear in branch 128's history, is irrelevant - neither appears in the history of master, because they will _both_ be replaced by the squash-merge commit.

Comment: It's not irrelevant if you are in a deep enough hole and need to find an automated solution to get out of it. In that case the author of 158 could recover the original commit history and make it available to you, allowing you to rebase your commits on top, thereby properly inheriting the renames and the like. BUT if he did a `commit --amend` of `commitA`, even that would not be possible.

Comment: @Inigo I think you're mistaking me for the OP; I didn't come here looking for help, I came here offering it. My point is that any rebase of branch 124 would need to be on top of _the squash merge_, since that's the only version of branch 158 that is now part of the project's history. You're right that they might have rewritten history _twice_, but it doesn't really change the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232810/discussion-between-inigo-and-imsop).

Answer (score 1):

A very useful rule to enforce in any git workflow is that you should never rewrite history which you have already shared.

In your example, the early work on branch 158 was shared with branch 124. However, you then used the "squash" merge option, which *rewrites history*, creating a single commit from multiple. That means git has no way to know that the changes in 124 are related to the new version of 158, so when you merge 124 to master, it's going to try to merge those *all over again*.

If you had instead performed a straight-forward merge (both when merging to branch 124 and when eventually merging to master), creating a merge commit with the full history of 158 preserved, the PR to merge 124 would simply have skipped over the commits which were shared between the branches.

However, it sounds like you also have a more organisational problem: if a developer picks up changes from an in-progress branch, it is *essential* that they communicate with the author of that branch. What if a problem was found with 158, and a PR for 124 was opened before 158 was merged? What if the author of 158 had abandoned their initial branch and started again?

If the two developers are communicating properly, it is *possible* for the author of 158 to safely rewrite the history of their branch (with a rebase, a squash merge, etc) - the author of 124 just needs to know about it, and rewrite *their* history to match, using `git rebase`. It's usually easier to avoid that where possible though.

Comment: Totally agree. But there is a second factor that I'm trying to get the OP to clarify. Besides the squash merge into master, it sounds like even the originally shared commit, 158-`commitA`, was amended (i.e. history rewritten) *before* the merge into master, meaning even a straight merge would not have helped.

Comment: @Inigo I've added a quick note that to skip over the commits, _both_ merges need to be full merge commits.

Comment: Agreed. Basically the rule is avoid rewriting *any* shared history, be it commits on master or even shared patches.

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks for this great answer , I've thought about `squash-merge` might remove the history and cause this situation, but I haven't test this until I caught this in work. Besides, I'm thinking if 158 was not closed after merged into master, It might leave a latest commit for me(124) to sync , would it be a alternative way, still it is not that "automatically". FYI, our project force developers to use squash-merge when PR

Comment: @Caper As I say, there is a communications problem if you only found about the extra changes after they were merged; git cannot fix that. Merging the extra changes across might have helped; but depending on the changes involved and how they were made, it might lead to confusing conflicts when you merge to master. Ultimately, a policy of using squash merges probably assumes that all branches are independent; it's explicitly throwing away any information about relationships between them. If you can't change that policy, you'll need to be _even more pro-active_ at communicating.